# Inserting list element in next to last position

Tags: javascript, jquery

Given a HTML unordered list

```
<ul id = "master_key_list">
  <li id="master_key_23" class="available_element">Fix the Peanut Butter</li>
  <li id="master_key_24" class="available_element">Focus on Price Sensitivity</li>
  <li id="master_key_25" class="available_element" >Focus on Messaging</li>
  <li id="master_key_26" class="available_element">Create Growth and Retention Funnels</li>
  <li id="new_bp_element_element" class="available_element">Additional Best Practice?</li>
</ul>
```

how can I add another list element before the last list element?

I've tried

```
$("#master_key_list li:last").before("<li />").append(appendString);
```

where `appendString` is a valid concatenated HTML text.  However, all this is doing is overwriting the last list element text, rather than actually inserting it.

Answer (score 1):

```
$("<li>new text</li>").insertBefore($("#master_key_list li:last"));
```

[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/v5fVm/)

Answer (score 0):

You *are* inserting a new list item, but the text alters the original `li` selected.

Instead of using `append`, use `insertBefore`:

```
$("<li />", { text: appendString }).insertBefore("#master_key_list :last-child");
```

Here's the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/4GhbW/

Answer (score 0):

I think what you need is

```
$('<li />', {
    text: appendString
}).insertBefore('#master_key_list li:last')
```